# Proof in graph theory: maximum degree of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem in graph theory:

> Prove that for every graph $G = (V, E)$ with $E \neq \varnothing $, it is true that: $$\Delta (G) \geq \left \lceil \frac{\left | E \right |}{\min\left \{\frac{\left | V \right |}{2} , \tau (G)\right\}} \right \rceil$$
>   where $\Delta (G)$ indicates graph's maximum degree, and $\tau (G)$ is the vertex number, i.e, the minimum number of vertex needed to cover all edges of the graph.

but I can't really think of any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show $\Delta(G) \ge 2|E|/|V|$ and $\Delta(G) \ge |E|/\tau(G)$.
The first inequality is a consequence of the [handshake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma). For the second, consider a set of $\tau(G)$ vertices that covers all edges of the graph, and consider the sum of the degrees of these vertices.